# How can I create a windows service in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, windows-services

I have been assigned an assignment to create such a service in delphi which will track the *logged* in user activity on the computer. For this i have to

1. I want my service to be run in the background and should store the name of every ACTIVE window in particular time events.
2. Learn how to create windows service in delphi

How should I get started?

Comment: Please see this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/404196/ethics-of-assisting-other-programmers-where-do-we-draw-the-line

Comment: This hardly seems to cross the line of a program for unethical usage.  If anything it is someone asking you to do their work for them.

Answer (score 6):

Create a Windows service in Delphi:

http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Delphi-Kylix/Creating-a-Windows-Service-in-Delphi/

Answer (score 1):

You will want to do some research in the [CBT hooks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997537.aspx) provided by the Microsoft SDK.  They include the ability to be notified each time a window is created, among other things.

Answer (score 0):

The Service code from Aldyn is able to track logged in users. Not sure if it is what you want, but it must surely be a good start. The vendor goes through fits of activity and sleep, so be sure it does what you want as-is.
[Aldyn SvCOM](http://www.aldynsoftware.com/svcom.html)